# ¿Cómo filtrar TIMESTAMPs solo por fecha en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Por ejemplo , tengo un campo **TIMESTAMP** y un registro es algo como `'2021-04-23 14:17:46'` en mi base de datos , y quiero buscar los registros que empiecen por `'2021-04-23'`, es decir una parte del TIMESTAMP, en SQL. ¿Cómo podría buscarlo?

Comment: Y que usas? Mysql, sql server.....?

Comment: @BetaM perdona se me ha olvidado comentarlo. Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: SQL Developer es el IDE, y con él puedes abrir varios tipos de bases de datos, así que volvemos a preguntar y qué usas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si querés filtrar solamente por fecha, podés usar `TRUNC`.

Es bueno darse un paseo por la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm):

> La función `TRUNC(fecha)` retorna *fecha* con la porción de la hora del día truncado a la unidad especificada por el modelo de formato *fmt*.

***fmt* es opcional**, por lo tanto no es necesario que la agregues en la función (en este caso).

Un ejemplo con la fecha de hoy:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

> 23/04/21 09:25:47,308894 -04:00

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
```

> 23/04/2021

En una cláusula `WHERE`, asumiendo que la tabla se llama *test*, que tiene una columna *cl* de tipo `TIMESTAMP` cuyo valor es un timestamp de hoy:

```
SELECT t.cl
FROM TEST t
WHERE TRUNC(t.cl) = TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

> 23/04/21 09:25:47,308894 -04:00

Comment: Pero con eso lo que haces es convertir a un NUMBER , yo quiero que me busque todas las que comiencen por X y que sigan siendo timestamp

Comment: `TRUNC` trabaja con _number_ y _date_. El ejemplo que di es nada más como referencia, ya que la columna seguirá siendo timestamp cuando lo filtres a través de un `WHERE`.